# Runtime Error 3075 VBA Access Format Date Error

Tags: date, ms-access, vba, runtime-error

I always get the Runtime Error 3075: Syntaxerror in the Date '#10.08.2017 15:27:16'. My code looks like this:

```
Dim ActID As Integer
ActID = Me!Of_ID

DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE BD_Offer SET BD_Offer.Of_Timestamp = #" & Format(Now, "DD.MM.YYYY HH:NN:SS") & "# WHERE BD_Offer.Of_ID = '" & ActID & "';"
```

When I change the *#" & Format & "#* quotes to *'" & Format & "'*

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE BD_Offer SET BD_Offer.Of_Timestamp = '" & Format(Now, "DD.MM.YYYY HH:NN:SS") & "' WHERE BD_Offer.Of_ID = '" & ActID & "';"
```

then I get the Runtime Error 3464: Dataconflict.

Of_Timestamp has the Datetyp and Of_ID is Autofilled with Integer as Primary Key.

Thanks for replies

Luca

Comment: [Reading material](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html) for proper use of dates in Access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a valid format:

```
BD_Offer.Of_Timestamp = #" & Format(Now, "yyyy\/mm\/dd hh\:nn\:ss") & "#
```

When Of_ID is an AutoNumber, you also must provide a *numeric* parameter:

```
"UPDATE BD_Offer SET BD_Offer.Of_Timestamp = #" & Format(Now, "yyyy\/mm\/dd hh\:nn\:ss") & "# WHERE BD_Offer.Of_ID = " & ActID & ";"
```

However, you may simply get away with:

```
"UPDATE BD_Offer SET BD_Offer.Of_Timestamp = Now() WHERE BD_Offer.Of_ID = " & ActID & ";"
```

Comment: Why all the \ characters??

Comment: @Brad: That's because slash and colon here are not literals but only placeholders for the localized date and time separators. Thus, these can turn out to be anything else than what is accepted by Access SQL. The backslash escapes a character; thus forces slash or colon in the formatted string in any environment.

Comment: Interesting. So this same string could result in `2017-08-10 11:53.59` on another system where on mine it output `2017/08/10 11:53:59`?

Comment: @Brad: Yes. The date string would be accepted, but indeed _dot_ and _space_(!) as the localized separator will cause problems.

Comment: @Gustav Thanks for your reply but when I do it like you wrote I get the Runtime Error 3464: Dataconflict. I'm really confused because everything I'm doing is not working.

Comment: @Gustav Thanks a lot, I wasn't looking for the last part, now everything is working!